# Slow query in SQL Server with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, optimization, left-join

I'm searching a way to optimize a SELECT query with a left join between a date dimension table and a fact table which have to display the sum of a measure for the year 2014.

Here is the query :

```
select SUM(coalesce(f.NBSCANS,0)) as somme
from DIM_DATE as d 
left join FCT_SCAN as f
on d.DATE = CAST(f.DATE_HEURE as DATE)
and CAST(d.HEURE as varchar(4)) = CAST(CAST(f.DATE_HEURE as time) as varchar(4))
where d.ANNEE = 2014
```

This query is too slow because I've never seen the results.
If I add a WHERE clause on the month (ex : d.MOIS = 11) it takes 1 minute (so a little long).

But if I add a WHERE clause on the day too like this the results are displayed in 4 seconds :

```
select SUM(coalesce(f.NBSCANS,0)) as somme
from DIM_DATE as d 
left join FCT_SCAN as f
on d.DATE = CAST(f.DATE_HEURE as DATE)
and CAST(d.HEURE as varchar(4)) = CAST(CAST(f.DATE_HEURE as time) as varchar(4))
where d.ANNEE = 2014
and d.MOIS = 11
and d.JOUR = 5
```

For information, here are the CREATE TABLE script of DIM_DATE :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_DATE](
    [DATE_HEURE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ANNEE] [int] NULL,
    [MOIS] [int] NULL,
    [JOUR] [int] NULL,
    [DATE] [date] NULL,
    [JOUR_SEM_DATE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [NUM_JOUR_SEM_DATE] [int] NULL,
    [HEURE] [time](0) NULL,
    [TRANCHE_1H] [time](0) NULL,
    [TRANCHE_DEMIH] [time](0) NULL,
    [TRANCHE_QUARTH] [time](0) NULL,
    [TRANCHE_10M] [time](0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_DATE] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DATE_HEURE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The DATE_HEURE field in FCT_SCAN is the same that in DIM_DATE.

In DIM_DATE there is a record every 10 minutes :

```
DATE_HEURE
2015-06-17 12:00:00.000
2015-06-17 12:10:00.000
2015-06-17 12:20:00.000
2015-06-17 12:30:00.000
2015-06-17 12:40:00.000
2015-06-17 12:50:00.000
2015-06-17 13:00:00.000
2015-06-17 13:10:00.000
2015-06-17 13:20:00.000
2015-06-17 13:30:00.000
```

So my question is the following : how to optimize this query knowing that I have to keep the LEFT JOIN? (for a Cognos package)

Edit : Here is the execution plan.

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=CASE WHEN [globalagg1013]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [globalagg1015] END))
   |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([globalagg1013]=SUM([partialagg1012]), [globalagg1015]=SUM([partialagg1014])))
        |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
             |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1012]=COUNT_BIG([Expr1007]), [partialagg1014]=SUM([Expr1007])))
                  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=CASE WHEN [DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN].[NBSCANS] as [f].[NBSCANS] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN].[NBSCANS] as [f].[NBSCANS],0) ELSE (0) END))
                       |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([d].[DATE], [Expr1009]))
                            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1009]=CONVERT(varchar(4),[DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE].[HEURE] as [d].[HEURE],121)))
                            |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE] AS [d]), WHERE:([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE].[ANNEE] as [d].[ANNEE]=(2014)))
                            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1003]) OPTIMIZED)
                                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1021]=BmkToPage([Bmk1003])))
                                 |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1019], [Expr1020], [Expr1018]))
                                 |         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:(([Expr1019],[Expr1020],[Expr1018])=GetRangeThroughConvert([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE].[DATE] as [d].[DATE],[DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE].[DATE] as [d].[DATE],(62))))
                                 |         |    |--Constant Scan
                                 |         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN].[IDX_DATE_HEURE] AS [f]), SEEK:([f].[DATE_HEURE] > [Expr1019] AND [f].[DATE_HEURE] < [Expr1020]),  WHERE:([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[DIM_DATE].[DATE] as [d].[DATE]=CONVERT(date,[DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN].[DATE_HEURE] as [f].[DATE_HEURE],0) AND [Expr1009]=CONVERT(varchar(4),CONVERT(time(7),[DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN].[DATE_HEURE] as [f].[DATE_HEURE],0),121)) ORDERED FORWARD)
                                 |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([DECIS_DM_PARCOURS_PAX].[dbo].[FCT_SCAN] AS [f]), SEEK:([Bmk1003]=[Bmk1003]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: I suspect a loop join here. I had same problem. Can you post the execution plan? In case it say loop join, would you try to change "left join" in "left hash join"?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the execution plan, I found the solution. It was an index for the DATE_HEURE field of FCT_SCAN which has cost a lot in the query so I deleted it.
Now the execution time is about few seconds.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions !

Comment: please try the posted answers. I am sure some of them are faster and more readable than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. It should improve performance alot. You could improve it even more by creating a computed column PERSISTED in the tabel FCT_SCAN. That would allow use of index.

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(SUM(f.NBSCANS),0) as somme
FROM
  DIM_DATE as d 
LEFT JOIN
  FCT_SCAN as f
on 
  f.DATE_HEURE>= d.DATE_HEURE
  and f.DATE_HEURE < dateadd(minute, 10, d.DATE_HEURE)
WHERE
  d.ANNEE = 2014
  and d.MOIS = 11
  and d.JOUR = 5
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.

Comment: try now, i had a typo HEURE instead of DATE_HEURE

Comment: I found the solution and I wrote it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Non-equi-joins are always bad.

You should change the logic: Truncate f.DATE_HEURE to 0/10/20/30/40/50 minutes and then join.

```
select SUM(coalesce(f.NBSCANS,0)) as somme
from DIM_DATE as d 
left join 
  ( select
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATE_HEURE) / 10 * 10, 0) as x
      , ...
    from FCT_SCAN
  ) as f
on d.DATE = f.x
where d.ANNEE = 2014
```

Adding a similar condition on FCT_SCAN.DATE_HEURE to restrict to the same period (e.g. year 2014) might also help.